# Passing a variable from link_to to a modal in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table of results that have an attribute email. I want to be able to pass the object to my modal in rails. Seem not to be able to pass the object so that i can call it in my modal.

*index.html.erb*

```
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" id="email-template-user-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <%= render "shared/email_template_user"%>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<p class="email">
  <% @banker_assignments.each do |application| %>
    <%= link_to application.loan_application.email, lp_banker_assignments_email_status_path(application), class: 'email-template-user-modal', id: "email-template-user-id", :data => { :toggle => "modal", :target => "#email-template-user-modal", :email => application.loan_application.email, :id => application.loan_application.id, :application => application } %> 
  <%= end %>    
</p>
```

*assignments_controller.rb*

```
def email_status
  ap params        
end
```

*routes.rb*

```
post '/lp_banker_assignments/email_status' => 'lp_banker_assignments#email_status'
put '/lp_banker_assignments/email_status' => 'lp_banker_assignments#email_status'
get '/lp_banker_assignments/email_status' => 'lp_banker_assignments#email_status'
```

*_email_template_user.html.erb*

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title">Compose Email</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-12">

      <%= form_tag :action => 'email_status', class: 'form-horizontal' do %> 
        <div class="">
            <div class="col-md-3">Recipient</div>


          <div class="col-md-9">
            <%= email_field_tag "recipient", <%= application.email %>, class: " string optional form-control"%>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">Cc to:</div>
          <div class="col-md-9">
            <%= email_field_tag "cc_to", <%= application.second_email %>, class: " string optional form-control" %>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-3">
            Subject
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-9">
            <%= text_field "subject", "", class: "subject string optional form-control" %>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-3">
            Content
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-9">
          <%= text_field "content", ""%>

          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3"></div>
          <div class="col-md-9">
            <%= submit_tag %>
        </div>
        </div>
      <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried a lot of options with jquery and all but I cant seem to know how to get the object from my index.html.erb to my modal view.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= link_to application.loan_application.email, 
lp_banker_assignments_email_status_path(application), 
class: 'email-template-user-modal', id: "email-template-user-id", 
:data => { :toggle => "modal", :target => '#email-template-user-modal_' + application.loan_application.id, 
:email => application.loan_application.email, :id => application.loan_application.id, :application => application } %>
```

Your modal code

```
<div class="modal fade" id="<%= 'email-template-user-modal_%s' % [application.loan_application.id] %>">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    ...content
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i get an error undefined local variable or method 'application' @sontya

Comment: where you have this code for modal, in the same page right?

Comment: pass `application` object  `<%= render "shared/email_template_user, locals: {application: application}"%>`

Comment: that also throws an error as well locals is not a valid ruby identifier

Comment: yes d code for d modal is in d same page the content for the modal is in d partial file

Comment: try this `<%= render :partial => 'shared/email_template_user', :locals => { :application => application } %>` and I am updating my answer too

Comment: back to the first error undefined local variable or method 'application'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73660/discussion-between-sontya-and-kingsley-simon).